# Tengo una duda/problema con el replace de java

Tags: java

Tengo en un array llamado personas, el resultado de una función que devuevle un array de nombres y apellidos de personas generadas aleatoriamente. Tal y como se muestra en la imagen.
La cuestión es que hay un apellido que es *del-Arc*o, el cual quiero que en vez de ser del-Arco, pase a ser *del Arco* (separado). El problema viene porque del-Arco se almacena en una única posicion[i], mientras que del Arco se almacena en 2.

```
System.out.println("Lista de personas con (del-Arco)");
    String[] personas=FunPersonas.generarPersonasAleatorias((byte)7);
    System.out.println(FunPersonas.imprimeArray(personas));
    String personas2[]=new String[personas.length];
    for(byte i=0; i<personas.length; i++) {
        if(personas[i].contains("del-Arco")) {
            personas[i]= personas[i].replace("-"," ");
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println("Lista de personas con (del Arco)");
    System.out.println(FunPersonas.imprimeArray(personas));
    
    
    Random r=new Random();
    System.out.println("Genera una persona aleatoria de la Lista (Personas)");
    String[] persona=personas[r.nextInt(personas.length)].split(" ");
    System.out.println(FunPersonas.imprimeArray(persona));
    
    if(persona[persona.length-1].equals("Hombre")) {
        System.out.print("El señor ");
    }else {
        System.out.print("La señora ");
    }
    
    System.out.println(persona[1]+" "+persona[2]+ " ha sido acusada del asesinato");
```

Estas imagenes, muestran un ejemeplo de lo que sucede

[image: ejemplo imagen del arco]

[image: ejemplo resultado de del-Arco]

Lo que quiero es que el apellido "*del Arco*" se almacene en 1 única posición, tal y como lo  haría *del-Arco*

Comment: El problema no está en replace, sino en split: estás asuminendo que la primera palabra es el nombre y las dos siguientes los dos apellidos. Tendrías el mismo problema con un nombre compuesto como "Juan Francisco"

Comment: Gracias, tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 1):

Eso se debe al uso de [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ,al pasarle como parametro (" ") estas generando un nuevo array por cada espacio que encuentre en cada posición,y como estas usando `replace()`,adicionalmente estas generado un espacio en el apellido del-Arco.Entonces podrias usar primero `split()` antes del `replace()`

```
Ejemplo:

String[]personas={"Juan mendez del-Arco (19/11/1991) -Mujer","pedrito alimañan (24/12/2022) -Hombre"};

String []nombres=personas[0].split(" ");

 for(byte i=0; i<nombres.length; i++) {
            if(nombres[i].contains("-")){//hay otro("-")que eliminar -mujer
            nombres[i]= nombres[i].replace("-"," ");
        }
    }
```

como salida tendras lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, no había caído en ese detalle.